# Please give basic example of class that derives from ScrollableControl and implements IContainerControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a container that will scroll into view a control that has been appended to the container's `Controls` collection.  I am starting with the [ContainerControl class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol?view=netframework-4.8) and following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ContainerControl__ctor).

I've implemented the `ActivateControl` method and the `ActiveControl` property as required by the `IContainerControl` interface.

I have added controls to the container's Controls collection; there are no errors, but nothing is visible on the screen.

I'm instantiating the container like this:

```
    MyContainer container1 = new MyContainer();
    MyContainer.Name = "container1";
```

Here's the class declaration:

```
  public class MyContainer : ScrollableControl, IContainerControl
  {  
        public MyContainer() { }
  }
```

EDIT: I've gotten the control to be visible by enabling the vertical scroll-bar, but although I've added a dozen controls (composite user controls) to the Controls collection, only one is visible. Do their physical positions need to be specified?

Comment: If you only add a control and want to show it, why not use a Panel and `panel.ScrollControlIntoView(control)` after adding the new `control` to the `Controls` of the panel ? Therefore if you want to create a user control for that, you can just inherit from Panel.

Comment: I am adding dozens of composite user controls to the container.  Can Panel stack multiple controls vertically?

Comment: Yes, no problem, but check that and you'll know. Panel is a ScrollableControl. I done that and there is no problem with up to more than ~500 controls having one label and one textbox with context menu, in addition to 50 labels, which makes a total of nearly 1000 controls. It lags a little (2-3s) on the creation process but not when having only a total of 200 for example. And after creation, there is no problem at all with the scrollbars. When I have a total of 2000 controls, it takes 7s to generate them and after the panel is fine. I don't think you will get better using a ScrollableControl.

Comment: A FlowLayoutPanel can do this already.

Comment: See the example for the [LayoutEngine Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.layout.layoutengine?view=netframework-4.8) to learn how to control the layout of the contained controls.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Thank you for that link.